# How to disable confirmation dialogs for simple operations

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have just started using Blender (for video editing), and I have run into one thing that just drives me crazy.

Whenever I try to do even the most trivial operation, there is a popup asking to confirm that I want to do it. There is no purpose for this, as there is an undo feature, and it is a constant annoyance.

Is it possible to disable this feature? If so, how?

Comment: what actions are you getting conformations for?

Comment: Save file, and delete strips, mainly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the save confirmation you could try this addon [Simple Carnival Save File No Confirmation](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?372967-Add-on-Simple-Carnival-Save-File-No-Confirmation)